# Parse retrieve a particular user information and display it (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, parse-platform

I would like to pull all information of a particular user stored in parse and display it on my website.
What I mean by particular, is that user would enter the objectID of a user in a textfield, and the value of that textfield would be use to pull all information of that user from the parse database.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

  // ***************************************************
  // NOTE: Replace the following your own keys
  // ***************************************************
  var userID = document.getElementById("txtUserID").value;

    Parse.initialize("ID", "ID");


 var userInfo = new Parse.Object("User");
  var query = new Parse.Query(userInfo);  


  query.include("Addresss");
  query.include("name");

  query.equalTo("objectId", userID);
  query.find({
    success: function(results) {
      res.send(results)  

    },
    error: function(error) {
       console.error("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
    }
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>


  <input name="txtUserIDName" id="txtUserID" type="text" value="test">


</body>
</html>
```

My question now that the user has entered the objectid, and that parse has retrieve it (not sure if my code to retrieve is proper), how to display information about that particular user like address on screen to the user.

Comment: Your query isn't set up properly. See the documentation for details: <https://parse.com/docs/js_guide#users-querying> In summary, you need to create a query with var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User); and then add you objectId field with query.equalTo("objectId",userID); (Keep in your includes as well if they are pointers, but it looks like they aren't so you shouldn't need them. That simply tells Parse whether it should fetch the PFObject's stored at those keys or if it should keep them as simply unfetched pointers. Strings, numbers, etc don't need this call)

Answer (score 0):

Use get method to get the fields:-

```
success: function(results) {

  console.log(results.get('email'));

},
```